# How to get path of file to save data after getting data from server?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, macos

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strFileUrl]]; //strFileURL is url of my video/image
NSURLConnection *conection = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO] autorelease];
[conec start];
[request release];
```

with use of above code i am creating URL connection to download data from server.

```
strFilePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:strFileName];
```

with use above code  i can get path of file to save data, but in the above code i don't know how to get `strFileName` (at last in the above code) or please any one help me how to save data into my document directory after getting data from server. Advance thanking to all.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Capturing server response

 NSData* result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request  returningResponse:&response error:&error];

 NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];   
 NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[(NSURLResponse *)response suggestedFilename]]; 


 NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:result attributes:nil];
```

Comment: I think with use of above code, we are assigning name to the image.., but actually i have to store with the same name whatever is there in the server. Please don't mind give me answer, actually i am new to this language. Thank you very much for providing answer. @Shashank

Comment: Hi sorry for disturbing once again, i think you are using "response" as a string but you didn't say which value we have to define for that "response" variable. if you don't mine please define that variable. @Shashank